# Login form using HTML

Tags: php, html, css

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>SampleLogin</title>
    <style>
    .center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height:60%;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    text: bold;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:powderblue;>

    <form action="dgdsg.php" method="post">
    <fieldset  class="center">
    <legend>Login Details:</legend>
     Username:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" ><br>
     Password:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Above code is of  login form.In this form tag  the  dgdsg.php file which I have mentioned is not exist.I was expecting an error at run time after click on submit button but nothing is happening at run time.

Plz suggest necessary changes.

Comment: Where is your php file also?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? You should encounter an error, and that is `dgdsg.php` does not exist

Comment: Try to read https://html.com/attributes/form-method/ for Basics

Comment: You are not closing the style attribute in `style="background-color:powderblue;` . Should be  `style="background-color:powderblue;"`

Comment: I was expecting that it will show error like file is missing. But after clicking on submit button nothing is happening.

Comment: style="background-color:powderblue; .    Should be style="background-color:powderblue;"  

After doing above changes its working as expected. Thank you SearchAndResQ

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by SearchAndResQ:

```
style="background-color:powderblue;
```

Should be

`style="background-color:powderblue;"`

After doing above changes it's working as expected.